# Cat Palm! Please help

Tags: indoors, palm

Please help! I don't know what to do to make my Cat Palm start doing better. I've tried everything that I can think of. I only use distilled water. At first the tips started to turn brown. And then they started to turn yellow. Then entire leaves would start to turn yellow, which I pruned off. I'm not sure if I need to repot it or not, as some of the roots are becoming exposed. This week it also started to turn yellow on the trunk. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a photo of the plant maybe of the details like the roots you mentioned? Also interesting would be your watering and fertilizing routine and how much light the palm gets. You can always [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: A photo of the underside of the leaf will show if there are bugs too

Comment: I tried to add photos but it wouldn't allow me to upload anything. So I'm attaching links to photos I'm not sure if that will work either. I used to still water.. and I only water when the top part of the soil seems dry because I read that I may be overwatering it. I've been doing this new watering schedule for several months and that hasn't helped either. I've tried plant food diluting it to half of the usual recommended amount for other plants.. as several websites said to do so.

Comment: (^^^I meant I use distilled water) Photos
https://photos.app.goo.gl/UbrYVCCtnTMkncRT6
https://photos.app.goo.gl/K6pM8kZveKwz84MX7
https://photos.app.goo.gl/GmAhYqVrLCjeWtGE6
Those blue granuals are leftover fertilizer from when the plant was bought about 8 months ago